# Is the Android action bar suitable for advanced search

Tags: android, android-actionbar, search-form

I read that the Android action bar is **recommended** for search instead of implementing search within the app UI. In my app there is a need for **an advanced search mechanism**, so I was thinking in terms of a search form.

> Would you still recommend the action bar for this?

**Example of search:**

```
Find all players born between 1990 and 1995 from region 1 or 2 who have a rating of more than 2000 points.
```

Comment: See here the difference of manually search and global vs local search.. http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-adding-search-to-your-apps/

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

My opinion is that you should implement it in a dialog. And add it to the overflow of the actionbar.